# Am I even connecting to Oracle?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

When I attempt this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_objects WHERE object_type = 'TABLE'";
```

... I get an empty result set.

I have error_reporting() set to E_ALL, so I would assume that if it wasn't connecting correctly, I would be getting an error... right?

I'm using a class given to me by a higher-up that they use for everything, so it SHOULD work.

If you want that code, let me know.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me :).

**EDIT**

Here's the actual query function being executed:

```
/**
   * Query the database and store the result.  If the query is a select it returns the number of rows
   * fetched.
   *
   * Example:
   * <code>
   * $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
   * if($sql->query($query)){
   *  while($sql->fetch()){
   *      foreach($sql->results as $a=>$b){
   *        print "$a: $b<br>";
   *      }
   *      print "<hr>";
   *    }
   * }else{
   *    print "No results";
   * }
   *
   * </code>
   *
   * @param SQL*Plus query statement
   * @access public
   * @return int
   */
  function query($query_statement){
      if($_SESSION['TESTING']==1 && $_SESSION){
        $_SESSION['queries'][] = $query_statement;
        $_SESSION['Total_queries'] = count($_SESSION['queries']);
      }
    $parse_result = $this->execute($query_statement);
    if($parse_result == 0){
      return 0;
    }else{
      if($this->_queryresult){
        oci_free_statement($this->_queryresult);
      }
      $this->results=array();
      $this->_queryresult = $parse_result;
      $this->resultscount = oci_num_rows($this->_queryresult);
      if(!$this->resultscount)
        return 0;
      else
        return $this->resultscount;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Code is always helpful :) The oci_error function should provide further details.

Comment: oci_error() doesn't seem to output anything :(.

Comment: As for the code of the oracle class, I don't know enough about it as to not give away security flaws and such. :( I'll add the query function though.

Comment: Is `$parse_result` supposed to be zero on success, or does it have the number of returned rows? In which case what does it hold on error?

Comment: I didn't write that thing, so I'm not 100%. What it looks like to me is that $parse_result gets set to 0 only if $this->execute($query_statement) doesn't return anything.

Comment: Does the user you are connecting as actually have tables? Have you tried switching this to all_objects instead of user_objects ?

Comment: @Will: in that case, is `$this->execute()` wrapping `oci_execute()` and returning the result of an `oci_num_rows()` call? If `$parse_result` is actually the number of rows, passing **that** into `oci_num_rows()` wouldn't work would it? Don't you just want to return `$parse_result`? (And why is the result of an `execute` called `parse_result` instead of `execute_result`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make sure you display the errors, you can force one to check. You could also check the return value of the connect statement before you attempt to query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the query in SQL*Plus using the same connection information (username/password)? Perhaps your user doesn't have any table objects.

Comment: That query seems to work just fine if I run it through Oracle SQL Developer. :S